# SOSL Multiple Search Words

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl

Trying to search multiple terms in SOSL in APEX. I tried this singular, of course works:

```
[FIND 'searchOne' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ACCOUNT]
```

But these don't work:

- `[FIND 'searchOne' OR 'searchTwo' ....`
- `[FIND {'searchOne','searchTwo'} ....`
- `[FIND (searchOne', 'searchTwo') ....`

Error is:

> '(' not expected (or something..etc)

My goal is bulkification and searching a value in an Encrypted Field. I want to be able to get all matching records based on a set of terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apex, it's just a normal string:

```
[FIND 'searchOne or searchTwo' in all fields ...
```

This syntax is slightly different than the API, which is probably where the confusion is coming from. You can also use quotation marks (`"`) to group terms, etc, just like you can in normal SOSL.

```
[FIND '"searchOne" or "searchTwo"' in all fields ...
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: so if i had multiple string vars, would I write it as 'phoneVal  or emailVal' or would i need to keep it as ':phoneVal or :emailVal'?

Comment: @TristanBerger Not sure that syntax works. I'd just make it a normal string (e.g. `searchTerm`), and then merge that instead.

Comment: thanks that worked, had to concat a few things but it worked!