# SOSL Search with two terms from Search.query

Tags: apex, dynamic-sosl

I'm running a SOSL query in my Apex code using `Search.query`. My existing query with one term already works.

This

```
String queryString = 'FIND \'' + guid + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(My_Field__c)';
```

Executes as this

```
FIND '5559da13-afd7-4bd5-ae65-cd31dd439596' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(My_Field__c)
```

However, I now want to add another term with an `OR` condition. From the Query Editor in the Developer Console I can do this by wrapping the two terms, separated by `OR` with brackets ( { and }). So the following works from Developer Console.

```
FIND {5559da13\-afd7\-4bd5\-ae65\-cd31dd439596 or abc124} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(My_Field__c)
```

Although from Developer Console I don't put single quote around the values which `Search.query` seems to require.

So the result is trying to pass the following to `Search.query`.

```
FIND {'5559da13-afd7-4bd5-ae65-cd31dd439596' or 'abc123'} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(My_Field__c)
```

The result is an exception:

```
System.QueryException: expecting a string literal, found '{'
```

So my question is how do I format my search string to include the second condition to pass to `Search.query`? The `Search.query` function doesn't seem to accept the `OR` and brackets like the Developer Console Query Editor does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some undocumented reason, they decided to make SOSL in Apex *slightly* different than what's in the SOSL documentation. Instead of using `{}`, you use `''`. In other words, your Apex code would look like:

```
String searchQuery = 'FIND \'\\\'5559da13\\\\-afd7\\\\-4bd5\\\\-ae65\\\\-cd31dd439596\\\'' +
  ' or \\\'abc124\\\'\' IN ALL FIELDS '+
  'RETURNING Opportunity(My_Field__c)';
```

You use `\'` to escape a literal quote, `\\` to escape a literal backslash, and thus `\\\'` to escape a single quote as seen by SOSL, and `\\\\-` to escape a hyphen character.

Comment: @sfdxfox wow, that's a lot of slashes and single quotes. :) For my situation the search values are variables so lots of escape. I actually found another answer after trying different search terms in Google. The actual solution I used was actually answered by you as well. String queryString = 'FIND \'' + guid+ ' or ' + altId  + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(My_Field__c)'; https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257735/sosl-multiple-search-words

Comment: Note that this apex expression in FIND works `[FIND '"abc" or "def"'  IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(id, name)];` But same expression does not work in Search.query (or at least I couldn't figure out how)